# Wrong deposit in KuCoin. The depositor sent the deposit to the contract address

Tags: tokens, smart-contract-wallets, recover

The depositor sent the deposit to the contract address. Is there a way to know who the owner of the contact address is?

Comment: Please provide additional details about the contract address, such as the blockchain network (e.g., Ethereum, Binance Smart Chain) and any associated transactions or interactions.